# Insert different scripts based on environment in Next.js at runtime

Tags: html, reactjs, openshift, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to insert a script in my application's `<head>`, but the src attribute of that script depends on a runtime environment variable in my hosting server (OpenShift).

So if `process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "test"`, I want to insert `<script src="www.someurl.com/test.js" />` into the application's `<head>` and if it's "prod" then something else.

I have all these src values stored in a json file that I don't want to show up in the client. How do I make sure the client can receive the correct src from the server without having access to the json file with all the environment's endpoints?

**Express:**
With Express I used to just inject the src value into the window object at runtime before serving `index.html` but I'm not sure how to do it in Next.js

**Code:** Here's what I tried

```
// _app.tsx
...
      <Head>
        <script src={getScript()} type="text/javascript" />
      </Head>
...
```

where `getScript()` is a function in `<root>/scripts`

```
export function getScripts() {
  if (process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "test") {
    return scriptSrc.test;
  } else if (process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "prod") {
    return scriptSrc.prod;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can look into this document, https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Comment: No, actually this one's more relevant https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration since I'm looking for runtime config, not build time env variables.

But the problem is, I want those runtime secrets to have different values depending on what `process.env.ENVIRONMENT` is, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) to pass properties from the server to the client. Since the server has access to any runtime env variables, you can simply pass your variable to the client. In the render function use the env variable to decide which script to inject into the header.

This simple page showcases how to pass an env variable:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    return {
        props: {
            my_env: process.env.RUNTIME_ENV || 'default',
        }
    }
}

export default function MyPage(props) {
    return <div>{props.my_env}</div>
}
```

`npm run dev` renders "default" while `RUNTIME_ENV="foobar" npm run dev` renders "foobar".

Comment: Yes, getServerSideProps would actually solve my use case but it doesn't work in `_app.js` since that file doesn't support data fetching methods. And the scripts I'm trying to insert are something I want on every page (analytics), so it'd be a lot of code duplication to just throw getServerSideProps on every single page of the app.

Comment: I figured out a workaround. But it would've been much easier to do if the method you suggested worked in `_app.js`. I created an Issue for the feature request: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21528

Comment: Another option would be to use a [custom Document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) and put line 4 into the returned object in `getInitialProps`. Have you tried that? Might be easier than [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65890481/434227).

Comment: I think I skipped the entire section of `getInitialProps` when looking for solutions because the docs explicitly advise to try to avoid using it. I think it probably does solve my use case when used in `_document.js` but wouldn't that disable Automatic Static Optimization for the whole app? Also I don't understand why but for Nextjs above v9, they recommend not using it: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps The docs are a bit ambiguous on what are the tradeoffs when using `getInitialProps` but looks like it's better to avoid using it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I guess I would not use it without putting some serious tests in place. But technically it does work, I just have tested the implementation with Next.js v10.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to populate the data in `_app.js` at fetch time from the server since that file doesn't support `getServerSideProps` so I took the long road and did it client side instead.

**Step 1:**
Create an api route that returns back a JSON object with all the data you need in all the pages of the application. All `process.env` references work inside the `pages/api` folder since that code always runs on the server.

```
export default (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<StartResponseType>
) => {
  res.status(200).json(getScripts(process.env.ENVIRONMENT.trim()));
};
```

**Step 2:**
Now we need an efficient way to cache this response on the client since we don't want to keep fetching it for every page. I used `react-query` for this.

```
export function queryStart() {
  return useQuery<StartResponseType>("start", getStart, {
    staleTime: Infinity,
  });
}
```

**Step 3:**
We can't use the hook created above in `_app.js` until we wrap our `App` component in `QueryClientProvider`, so we need to create a Higher Order Component since there's no component that wraps `App`.

```
export const withQueryCache = (Page: any) => (props: any) => (
  <QueryCacheProvider>
    <Page {...props} />
  </QueryCacheProvider>
);
```

**Step 4:**
Now we just need to put it all together and add a loading state to the `App` so it only initiates the application once the initial data has been fetched.

```
// _app.tsx
function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const startQuery = queryStart();
  if (startQuery.isSuccess) {
    return (
      <>
        <Head>
              <script src={startQuery.data.scriptEndpoint} type="text/javascript" />
        </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
    );
  } else return <>Loading</>;
}

export default withQueryCache(App);
```

However, I would've still preferred for a way to just inject data from the server at fetch time. That would've been possible if `_app.js` file supported `getServerSideProps`. But until that's supported, this seems to be the best workaround.